# Agrupar y sumar un array descendentemente

Tags: javascript, reactjs

No logro formular una manera correcta este array que quiero agrupar y sumar

```
[
    {
        "rat": 90,
        "nam": "90"
    },
    {
        "rat": 70,
        "nam": "70"
    },
    {
        "rat": 50,
        "nam": "50"
    },
    {
        "rat": 90,
        "nam": "90"
    },
    {
        "rat": 90,
        "nam": "90"
    },
    {
        "rat": 50,
        "nam": "50"
    },
    {
        "rat": 40,
        "nam": "40"
    }
]
```

su salida quisiera que se mostrara de la siguiente manera: claro, no importa el orden, solo que se muestre de la manera ya mencionada; arriba de `"rat": 90` hay 3, entonces no se suma la cantidad total,  si lo que hay en este caso lo que quiero que salga salida 3

```
[
    {
        "rat": 3,
        "nam": "90"
    },
    {
        "rat": 1,
        "nam": "70"
    },
    {
        "rat": 2,
        "nam": "50"
    },
    {
        "rat": 1,
        "nam": "40"
    }
]
```

Comment: Deberías especificar mejor tu pregunta... en la respuesta porque rat=3? de donde sale? Recuerda que al preguntar debes ser lo mas específico posible, y mostrar que has intentado, pues nos podemos imaginar mil cosas (cuando no están especificadas). Revisa [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes recorrer tu array y verificar el valor de tu llave `nam`, si no existe, creas un nuevo valor en un nuevo array donde guardar tu resultado, y luego es cuestion de llevar un contador de las veces que ese valor se repite en tu recorrido.

```js
var entrada= [ { "rat": 90, "nam": "90" }, { "rat": 70, "nam": "70" }, { "rat": 50, "nam": "50" }, { "rat": 90, "nam": "90" }, { "rat": 90, "nam": "90" }, { "rat": 50, "nam": "50" }, { "rat": 40, "nam": "40" } ];

var resultado = [];
entrada.forEach(function(a) {
    if (!this[a.nam]) {
        this[a.nam] = {
            nam: a.nam,
            rat: 0
        };
        resultado.push(this[a.nam]);
    }
    this[a.nam].rat += 1;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Interesante funcionalidad `Object.create()` podrías ahondar un poco en ello?

Comment: Se trata de crear un objeto vacío que usaremos como `this` donde asignar el valor de `a`, mas o menos equivalente a crear un objeto con `{}`, lo use como control de mis objetos de `a` anteriores mediante el callback. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach